# No connector for [rabbitmq]

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

While setting up Rabbitmq in laravel, it returns this message when I try to queue a work.
It displays the error :

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1
```

**In QueueManager.php line 172:**

No connector for [rabbitmq]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the VYuldashev driver, I used https://github.com/AaronJan/Laravel-Rabbit - this driver.
and added the src/LaravelRabbit files in my vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add
`CLOCKWORK_ENABLE=false`
in your `.env` file.